# Gson.toJson(PrinterInfo) returns empty object

Tags: android, gson, parcelable

I'm trying to serialize an `android.print.PrinterInfo` object to JSON using Gson (version 2.9.0):

```kotlin
val type: Class<*> = data.javaClass
json.beginObject()
json.name(type.name)
json.value(gson.toJson(data, type))
Log.d(TAG, data.toString())
json.endObject()
```

but the result is an empty object `{android.print.PrinterInfo: {}}`. The log line clearly shows that the object is populated, there are no null values or similar (but using `GsonBuilder()` to include nulls, to pretty print or anything else doesn't make any difference). There are no exceptions, just no expected result.

Comment: Android Studio for some reason didn't inform about newer versions. Now I tried with the latest 2.10.1, no difference.

Comment: What will be the output of data.toString()?

Comment: PrinterInfo has a nice toString(), that emits a longish string in the format of "PrinterInfo{id=...,name=...,status=...}" Actually, I can solve the problem somewhat by providing a custom JsonSerializer for every single type involved (considering that these are nested structures, this means quite a lot of custom serializers, of course). But does that mean that Gson is practically unable to serialize anything but the simplest object with basic types?

Comment: Could you please include the full code you use to create the JSON and the logging call? I assume `json` is a `JsonWriter`, but your code does not include that, neither does it show where you log the JSON data. And `{android.print.PrinterInfo: {}}` in your question is not JSON (it is missing `"` around the member name); so maybe there could also be an issue in the way you create the JSON data?

Comment: I'll comment about the merits of the case below the answer but for the sake of completeness, you see the complete code except for a single call `val json = Gson()`. The rest compiles and works as a complete, standalone unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you are trying to serialize a class from the Android library without using a custom Gson adapter for this. In that case Gson will use reflection to access the fields of the class, including private fields which represent implementation details.

Even if this worked and you got a non-empty JSON object, it would contain internal data of the class, so it might differ between Android versions (maybe even between different Android devices?). And there is no guarantee that you can properly recreate a `PrinterInfo` object using `Gson.fromJson` this way. Possibly the `PrinterInfo` you would receive is in an inconsistent state and non-functional.

A better solution here would be either to write a custom Gson [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for the `PrinterInfo` class (and referenced classes) which performs the serialization (and deserialization).
Or because `PrinterInfo` implements `Parcelable` another option might be to use its `writeToParcel` method instead of serializing it as JSON.

In the future you can also use Gson's [`ReflectionAccessFilter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ReflectionAccessFilter.html) to avoid depending on reflection-based serialization of Android library classes by accident.

---

Arguably this does not answer *why* the JSON object in your question is empty, but it highlights that trying to (implicitly) use reflection for JSON serialization of third-party classes has its disadvantages, and that there are other alternatives.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, it required no less than ten separate type adapters. Considering that all of them are relatively straightforward data types, that was exactly what I had originally expected, Gson doing it for me. Mostly because its documentation clearly mentions that private fields are not only not a problem but explicitly recommended: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/UserGuide.md#finer-points-with-objects From that documentation, I had the -- probably false, I reckon -- impression that it's capable of doing it all by itself ...

Comment: ... and I only need to provide my own adapters if I want to do something differently than the stock conversion.

Actually, the rest is not that important. I don't particularly care about compatiblity with later Android versions because I don't store the data. I need the conversion in order to send it between two different parts of the same app in the present. And the two have different engines (Android/Kotlin and Flutter/Dart), so using parcels was out of question, too.

Comment: Gson should actually be able to serialize the `PrinterInfo` fields (it serializes anonymous and local classes as `null`, but that should not apply here). So `Log.d(TAG, Gson().toJson(data))` should give the desired result; I am not sure why it doesn't. But still I would not recommend to use it on `PrinterInfo` (or any third-party classes you don't control). The Gson user guide probably mentions `private` fields in the context of your own classes, whose structure you control.

Comment: Even using Gson's reflection-based serialization only temporarily at runtime could cause issues I guess when you use `Gson.fromJson`. If there are any fields whose values needs to be recomputed after creation and any classes which don't have a no-args constructor (see [`GsonBuilder.disableJdkUnsafe()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableJdkUnsafe())) you might get broken instances after deserialization.

Comment: Could well be. But I don't plan on using fromJson() at all, I only need the conversion in one direction. Actually, in both directions, I have to send the data but the other side will create its own objects from scratch. It will pick and use data from the JSON but it will use standard object creation and not deserialization.

Comment: But then your code which parses the JSON data has to know the field names and you have to hardcode them, right? But those are implementation details of the `PrinterInfo` class, so the parsing code might only work for the Android SDK you are testing locally, but not any other Android version users might be using where `PrinterInfo` might have different fields (e.g. in case they are renamed in the future).

Comment: I don't think the Android printing API would radically change any time soon, it's quite well established and modifying it would render quite a few programs unusable. And, as we established now, it doesn't serialize by itself anyway, so if I do my own, I can (and do) obviously use the same keys on both sides.